# Easiest way to share a link as Page from iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

What's the easiest way to share a link as a Facebook Page from an iOS app? I don't care if the solution isn't elegant, it's just for an internal tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this....

```
NSString *urlString = @"Your Link";
NSString *shareUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%@", urlString];
shareUrlString = [shareUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:shareUrlString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: That page doesn't support posting as a Page.